# If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the antiderivatives of $f(x)$, then $F_1=F_2$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Per question: True or false? If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the antiderivatives of $f(x)$, then $F_1=F_2$.

If I had $f(x) = 2x$, and I did an anti-derivative by $\int 2x dx = x^2 +c$. Does this mean because of $c$, the $F_1$ cannot equal  $F_2$?

Comment: The antiderivate is only unique upto an additive constant. But of course, you can choose the same antiderivate for $F_1$ and $F_2$, so they can be equal , but they need not be equal.

Comment: Note that antiderivatives of $2x$ are $x^2+c$, not $\frac12 x^2+c$.

Comment: As per the answer provided, this is a really badly phrased question.  They clearly intend it to mean then does $F_1$ HAVE to equal $F_2$.  Under that reading,  it's false.  Under actual reading, it's not answerable as it could be true or false depending on specific circumstances.  I'd point that out to the instructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't mean they *cannot* be equal. It means they aren't necessarily equal. If we know that $F_1'(x)=F_2'(x)=2x$, then it might be true that $$F_1(x)=x^2\\F_2(x)=x^2$$But we could also have $$F_1(x)=x^2+\pi\\F_2(x)=x^2-1000$$ So we can't conclude that $F_1=F_2$, but we also cannot prove $F_1\neq F_2$.

If this was a true / false question, then technically the statement $F_1=F_2$ is undecided. But by my powers of reading the minds of problem authors, they didn't mean to ask whether $F_1$ is equal to $F_2$, but whether $F_1$ is *necessarily* equal to $F_2$ (this is just an implicit part to many of these problems that really, really ought to be explicit), which means that the intended answer is "False". "Is it true that" is often used synonymously with "Does it follow that", and that's a shame.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking, that it is possible. So it can't be entirely false. Thanks for this @arthur

Answer (score 0):

As implied by others here,
$$F_1 = F_2 + C$$
if C can be chosen to match $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Essentially "... all antiderivatives are the same up to a constant."
[Wikipedia article on constant of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration)

Answer (score 0):

The statement is equivalent to:
$$F_1'=F_2'=f$$
but as others have touched on, the equality is not maintained for a definite integral. What this means is that whilst:
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}F_1\,dx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}F_2\,dx$$
$$F_1(x_2)-F_1(x_1)=F_2(x_2)-F_2(x_1)$$
this does not imply that either of the following are true:
$$F_1(x_1)=F_2(x_1)\\F_1(x_2)=F_2(x_2)$$
which is just the same as how:
$$2-1=100-99\nRightarrow 2=100$$

---

This is what it means for functions to differ by a constant, and how two functions can be antiderivatives of the same function